# c++ library for MPI-distributed containers

Tags: c++, mpi

Does anyone know of a c++ library that supports MPI-distributed containers?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like [Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/mpi.html)?

Comment: I have look into that briefly but does not seem to have distributed containers